# Trigger global touch/click events in javascript without specific target

Tags: javascript, events, touch, global, delegation

Since I'm searching for an answer for a while now and I'm still without any clue, I'll just describe my actual problem:

I need to build up automated touch/mouse gestures (tap,drag,pinch...) which I can fire on a webpage in order to test touch frameworks and their performance. Thus I want to trigger "global" touch/mouse events on a webpage with JavaScript without dispatching them from a specific element.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this or how these events are delegated in general?

Comment: Using Jquery, you can achieve a lot of what you looking for using trigger. [Jquery Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: I tried that concept as well but unfortunately you still need to trigger the event on a specific element. I need something that really simulates a click or touch on highest possible window/browser level so that I can dispatch an event closest possible to a "real" click, including recognition of the clicked element without knowing it before the event is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this just for the sake of emulating mobile touch actions on your browser, Chrome already has a tool for that. Check out [Mobile Emulation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#emulate-touch-events).

Comment: I already use the touch emulation of Chrome for general testing purpose. But what I want to achieve are kind of predefined actions like a swipe from point x to point y or a drag from x over y to z. Also I forgot to mention that I need this platform-/browser-independent, so that I can run a script predefined gestures on multiple devices and browsers in order to compare behaviour between them.